# How to show pdf in ios app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ipad

Can anyone tell me about how to show pdf on ios app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Tried this and this answer i got form one of SO Question.

```
NSMutableDictionary * paramms = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())", @"query",
                                nil];
[[StaticFacebook getFacebook] requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: paramms
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate: self];
```